# The whole wordpress website got RESET

Tags: wordpress, blogs

My wordpress blog was working perfectly fine, until one day when suddenly my blog got down. All I could see was a blank white page. I still don't know the reason.
But initially, I was able to figure out the Debug messages, which were some compatibility issues between  prototype of function Walker() and some theme function extending Walker(). So, I somehow managed to resolve those issues, by changing the theme function prototype.
But still, I could only view a blank page without any error. Then, I went through my child theme files and I found that there was some PHP code written to upload image file in child "style.css". Fortunately, I had backup of my Blog so I restored my child style.css.
After so many efforts, I still couldn't restore my complete Blog.
Although, All the posts and everything is there in DB, but I can't see any post on my Blog and Admin panel. It seems that my created categories are no longer there in Admin panel, when I restored theme.

Can anyone please help me to find out...
Why it happened and How my blog got reset ?
How can I restore my blog and reflect all my posts from DB to Admin-panel & Blog ?

Comment: This might be better asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It looks like somebody hacked you up. And, edited some files on your server.

Wordpress, actually doesn't offer any backup features. But, most of the web hosting services have a usual backup option. So, you might consider that.

Or, if your Wordpress database is right in place, as before, then you the possible error is that your Wordpress core files are corrupted or edited by anyone. So, you might consider, deleting your Wordpress and reinstalling it, (without deleting your databases). This would not affect your blog at all, because all Wordpress information is stored in the databases. But, remember to backup the files of wp-content folder and copy them to your new installation.